# SQL Join with "AND" + "OR" statement

Tags: php, sql, join

I am having trouble with this SQL statement. I am trying to restrict the results to the players with the ID's '25' and '87'. There is no error on the query ( I am getting every PID with this query)  This is the statement.

```
SELECT Rosters.PID, SUM( Rosters.Goals ) Goals, SUM( Rosters.Assists ) Assists, SUM( Rosters.PIM ) PIM, Rosters.TID, Players.pid, Players.firstname, Players.lastname, 
       SUM((Rosters.Goals + Rosters.Assists)) AS Points, Teams.tid, Teams.teamname
       FROM Rosters
       INNER JOIN Players
       ON Rosters.PID = Players.pid
       INNER JOIN Teams 
       ON Rosters.TID = Teams.tid
       WHERE ((Rosters.TID BETWEEN 9 AND 16) AND (Players.pid = 25 OR 87))
       GROUP BY 
       Players.pid
       ORDER BY Points DESC
```

I am almost certain this is the cause of my lack of SQL understanding, but W3C schools does not offer more complex solutions and the Stack threads I have looked up have been pretty localized.

[Here is the current output. It should just be the players with Id's 25 and 87](http://ecmayhem.com/battle.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in condition around `Players.pid`.

It should be

```
(Players.pid = 25 OR Players.pid = 87)
```

Logical `OR` operator combines two *logical* conditions. `Players.pid = 25` is valid condition, it evaluates either to boolean `true` or `false`. But `87` definitely does not evaluates to boolean value.

Comment: Thank you. That was an easy fix! Is there any instance when you don't have to retype the table name or column name in a situation like this?

Comment: @KurtLeadley Partially. You can get rid of full table names by using table aliases like `FROM Rosters as R` and so on. So you will be able to use `R.column_name` instead of `Rosters.column_name` in your query.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing that (sort of) at the start of my query. I just don't fully  understand when you need to declare and when not to declare tables/column names. That 2 credit SQL class did not do enough for me haha!

Comment: `(Players.pid = 25 OR 87)` will be always true. As you mentioned in last line **But 87 definitely does not evaluates to boolean value.**

Comment: @kamaldeepsinghbhatia Probably it will be true in *some DBMS*, but not in any. At least in MSSQL `Players.pid = 25 OR 87` is not a valid expression, and will raise an exception instead of evaluating to `true`.

Comment: Ya checked I've checked it for both and right it's not valid for MSSQL but for MySQL 

Answer (score 2):

Just change a part of your code from `Players.pid = 25 OR 87` To `Players.pid = 25 OR Players.pid = 87`

Comment: Thank you. Andy beat you to it, but I still up voted for ya. Is there any particular reason why the `Rosters.TID BETWEEN 9 AND 16` is okay but not `Players.pid = 25 OR 87`. I am guessing because the BETWEEN statement statement always has 2 arguments?

Comment: @KurtLeadley `Between` operator does not combines logical statements, it is separate operator having syntax `BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression`. In this case `AND` you're seeing has nothing to do with combining of logical expressions, it is part of `between` syntax.

Comment: Okay, I understand. That is what I figured after you answered my question

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can use IN construct to match Players.pid against list of possible values (note that the outer braces are not needed anymore):

```
WHERE Players.pid IN (25, 87) AND Rosters.TID BETWEEN 9 AND 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you think Players.pid would increase to check condition you could use IN operation and use like this

```
AND Players.pid IN (25,87) // You can add here more id to check
```

In place of your code

```
AND (Players.pid = 25 OR 87)
```